# AWS crawler could not classify the file type stores in S3 if its size >1MB

Tags: aws-glue

When iam trying to detect the file type using Crawler of size >=1MB of input Json file 
It creates a table in glue with is classification type is "Unknown".
But when the size is <1MB it successfully classifies the file type as JSON.

I crosschecked the file to ensure its a valid json file.

It is something a limitation for aws crawler.

If so is there any alternative to this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is by design of the crawler, if the meta data ( Internally crawler creates it) exceeds 1mb you'll get the above error, Crawler crawls 1mb for files that are more than 1mb  or the entire file if the file size is less than 1Mb. If the metadata itself doesn't fit 1Mb then the file will end up in Unkowntype.